# Нужен ли атрибут defer для скрипта который подгружается после страницы?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('a.lesson-audio-play.active').length > 0) {
        // include jwPlayer
        if ($('script[src^="core/modules/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"]').length === 0) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.src = 'core/modules/jwplayer/jwplayer.js';
            // s.defer = 'defer'; Нужно ли это?
            $('head').append(s);
        }
    }
});
```

Как правильно? желательно что бы скрипт был без задержек иначе какой то функционал не будет работать. Или же вобще лучше использовать `async` и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Взято [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script)
Атрибут `defer` говорит скрипту выполнится только тогда, когда будет загружен весь документ `$(document).ready()`.
Атрибут `async` говорит скрипту о немедленном его выполнении, как только он загрузится. Например:

```
function addScript(src){
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = src;
   script.async = false; // чтобы гарантировать порядок
   document.head.appendChild(script);
}

addScript('1.js'); // загружаться эти скрипты начнут сразу
addScript('2.js'); // выполнятся, как только загрузятся
addScript('3.js'); // но, гарантированно, в порядке 1 -> 2 -> 3
```

если будет стоять `script.async = true;` то скрипт, который загрузится первым и первый выполнится.
В вашем случае, если подгружаете скрипты и хотите немедленного их исполнения (как только загрузятся) то используйте `script.async = true`